# Объявление функции в setInterval в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Во время изучения React обнаружил следующий код:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
}
```

Почему перед `this.tick()` стоят `()`? Если я правильно понимаю это такой вид обьявления анонимной функции? Но ведь `setInterval` требует функцию на первом месте а `tick()` это метод данного класса, то есть и является функцией.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> **Выражения стрелочных функций** имеют более короткий синтаксис по
>   сравнению с [функциональными выражениями](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) и лексически привязаны к
>   значению [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (но не привязаны к собственному [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super),
>   или [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)).
>   Стрелочные функции всегда анонимные.

```
this.timerID = setInterval(
  () => this.tick(),
  1000
);
```

практически эквивалентно

```
let that = this;
this.timerID = setInterval(
  function () { return that.tick();},
  1000
);
```

---

> Зачем нужно объявлять анонимную функцию для вызова другой функции?

Так короче, удобнее и нагляднее.
Другим корректным вариантом было бы `setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000)`, иначе внутри tick не будет доступен объект по this. Это же метод объекта, не просто функция.

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос немного другой. Зачем нужно обьявлять анонимную функцию для вызова другой функции?

Comment: Так короче и удобнее и нагляднее. Другим корректным вариантом было бы `setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000)`, иначе внутри tick не будет доступен объект по this. Это же метод объекта, не просто функция.